# Allow Roles does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application with 2 folders. Administrator and Trainer which contain their respective pages. I have a web.config in each folder as below. When i login using these configuration settings, the user is denied access to his home page and if I remove deny users everybody can login. I have created roles and added user to the roles using WSAT.

***Web.Config For Administrator***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator" />
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

***Web.Config For Trainer***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Trainer" />
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Root Folder Web.Config File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="TSS" connectionString="Data Source = VC-SQL2008; Integrated
    Security=True;   database = aspnetdb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
</system.web>

<system.web>
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
 type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="TSS"
 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
 enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false"
 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
 applicationName="/"/>

  </providers>
  </membership>

  <profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"
  type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
   connectionStringName="TSS" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
 </profile>

 <roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="TSS" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
   type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <!--<add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />-->
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***web.sitemap example on how I have added roles***

```
enter<siteMapNode url="Administrator/Admin_Home.aspx" title="Home"  description=""
roles="Administrator">
```

***Login.aspx.cs***
    namespace TSS
    {
        public partial class Login2 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
              protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
               {
                   dbConnection dbConn = new dbConnection();
               }

```
  protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       // var a = Session["username"];
       string password = tb_password.Text;
       // Membership.CreateUser("s.g@visiblechanges.com", "9000");

       bool x = Membership.ValidateUser(tb_email.Text, password);
       string f_name;
       string l_name;
       string trainer="";
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       dt = TSS_WebService.getEmployeeByEmail(tb_email.Text);

       foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       {
            f_name = row["First_Name"].ToString();
            l_name = row["Last_Name"].ToString();
             trainer = row["First_Name"].ToString() + " " +   
           row["Last_Name"].ToString();
       }

   if (x == true)
  {

    Session["username"] = tb_email.Text;
    Session["trainer"] = trainer;

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(tb_email.Text, "Administrator"))
    {
         Response.Redirect("~/Administrator/Admin_Home.aspx");
    }

  if (Roles.IsUserInRole(tb_email.Text, "Trainer"))
  {

   Response.Redirect("~/Trainer/Trainer_Home.aspx");
  }

   if (Roles.IsUserInRole(tb_email.Text, "Salon Manager"))
   {

    Response.Redirect("~/Salon/Salon_Home.aspx");
   }

   if (Roles.IsUserInRole(tb_email.Text, "IT"))
    {

     Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
     }
   }

   else
   {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
   }
  }

  }
  }


***Login.aspx***
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Master.Master"     
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="TSS.Login2" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="BreadCrumbs" runat="server">
    <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server">
    </asp:SiteMapPath>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainArea" runat="server">
    <div id = "loginBox">
    <h2> LOGIN</h2>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_email" runat="server" class = "ipBox_large"></asp:TextBox><br 
    />
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_password" runat="server" class = "ipBox_large"></asp:TextBox>  
     <br />   
     <asp:ImageButton ID= "btn" ImageUrl = "../Images/btnLogin.gif" OnClick = 
     "submit_Click"  
     runat="server" />
     <asp:CheckBox id="NotPublicCheckBox" runat="server" /> 
     </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

I've been stuck with this for 2 days now and have researched everything I possibly could.Any help or advice is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: How about a role provider? Is it enabled for the site?

Comment: I have role manager enabled to true in my web.config. Is there something I am missing? I am not sure about role providers.

Comment: Please verify your question. As you cannot have two web.config in root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code instead of your `if(x==true){...}` Part if (x == true)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null) 
        {
            //redirect to the return url
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName.Text, NotPublicCheckBox.Checked);
        }

```
    /* create authentication cookie */
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tb_email.Text, NotPublicCheckBox.Checked)
    Session["username"] = tb_email.Text;
    Session["trainer"] = trainer;

    /*redirect depending on roles*/
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(tb_email.Text, "Administrator"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Administrator/Admin_Home.aspx");
    }

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(tb_email.Text, "Trainer"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Trainer/Trainer_Home.aspx");
    }

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(tb_email.Text, "Salon Manager"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Salon/Salon_Home.aspx");
    }

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(tb_email.Text, "IT"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
}
else
{
    /*Login error*/
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

Hope It works. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<deny users="?"/>`
rather than `<deny users="*"/>`

Comment: I tried it and it did not work! Is there something else that I might have missed out in my codebehind, sitemap or web.config file?

Comment: Deny users ?,* and allow roles "Administrator". This will prevent anyone other than Administrators from accessing the folder. The admin folder would inherit the allow of role "Trainers" from the parent config, the ?,* will block that out

Comment: @Nick Bork :: I think user1288906 has mistyped the question. As we cannot have two web.config in any directory. and here in the question he has provided two root directory web.config coding.

Comment: @Krishanu Dey - That was a mistake while I was pasting code here. I have only one web.config in the root directory and 1 in administrator folder and 1 in trainer folder. I have edited that.

Comment: The same can be done with using <location> tags in the root web.config.

Comment: @user1288906 :: If you are not using `<add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
` in anywhere in your application try removing it.

Comment: are you sure that your user is added to any role?

Comment: Yes I added it using the WSAT and my user is ticked and active in the role. Can I add a user to a role in code behind? Maybe I should try that.

Comment: Re-checked the membership tables and saw my users listed there as well with their appropriate role id's.

Comment: To do so use `Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName_Here, RoleName_Here);`

Comment: Can you update your question with your current html markup, codebehind and web.config

Comment: @Nick - Tried using the location path as u said. Does not make a difference.

Comment: @Krishanu - There isn't a whole lot I changed apart from Deny users = "?" and removeing the application name which is updated. Also removed allow roles in root folder web.config.

Comment: Check if your login is going ok. It will help me to sort out the problem if you post the html markup and code bhind of login.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have updated my question with the Login.aspx file and Login.aspx.cs file. If i place a breakpoint to check if the user is in a role., it is successfully going through the function.

Comment: You have to deny users *,? not just * and not just ? but both.